# No longer a dupe, needs reopening: w3wp.exe process was terminated due to stack overflow

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, reopen-closed

Looking for an admin to reopen this dupe question for which the cited original no longer exists

[How to debug: w3wp.exe process was terminated due to a stack overflow (works on one machine but not another)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053708/w3wp-exe-process-was-terminated-due-to-stack-overflow)

Thanks

Comment: The deleted original had no useful answers, so I'm inclined to agree. Voted to re-open.

Comment: I second that as I need an answer to that particular question!

Comment: It's odd that the system doesn't do anything when the original of a duplicate disappears. It should at least flag the orphan for moderator attn and potential reopening.

Answer (score 6):

The question has been...

## *Reopened!*